# Calculating LDA in matlab

Tags: matlab, lda

I have written the following code:

```
    %LDA 
file = xlsread('LDA.xlsx');
Graph=[];

for c=1:840 
    for  i=1:17  
        for j=18:34 
    Graph=[Graph,file(i,c),file(j,c)];
    end
    end
end 
lda=resubLoss(Graph)
```

but the func resubLoss does not work(Undefined function or variable 'resubLoss'.) I understand that it might be becuse of this is not a data set.

What i need is to calclute the same thing that this func does on my vector .

thank you.

Comment: What does "does not work" mean? Do you get an error message? Why is it a secret?

Comment: Undefined function or variable 'resubLoss'.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely (as can be guessed from https://de.mathworks.com/help/stats/classificationensemble.resubloss.html and https://de.mathworks.com/help/stats/classificationsvm.resubloss.html) this function can only be called with an object of the correct data type as its first argument, as it seems to be methods of said classes.

You need to make sure that you have objects of the wanted data type.

Comment: I assumed this is the problem, but how can I calculate the same think on my vector named Graph?